# Visual Studio - Release Folders

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I've done some searching around this issue, but I feel I may be having troubles as I don't know the correct terminology for this.

With my project I want to be able to just copy the release folder and run the .exe on any computer without having to install it on that machine - this works just fine.

However, there are a bunch of image and text files I wish to include in subdirectories which I have added manually to the release folder. This doesn't quite feel right though - it feels though there should be a way to have the files within the solution folder and for Visual Studio to create the subdirectories within the release folder and copy the files over upon build.

I would like the build to leave me with something that looks like this:

- /Release

  - /Images

    - image.bmp
  - /scripts

    - script.R
  - project.exe

How is this done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the directory and resources to your project solution.

Then set each document's 'Copy to Output Directory' property to 'Always Copy'.

This should trigger the documents to be copied to your Release directory on build.